# Can HiRISE see Perseverance?

Tags: perseverance, hirise

The rover Perseverance just landed last week. [HiRISE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HiRISE) can take high-resolution images of the surface of Mars. Will it be able to take pictures of Perseverance? (Has it already taken images of the Perseverance landing site?)

Comment: it started even before it touched down! https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50188/12102

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's HiRISE's picture of Perseverance and EDL hardware on the ground:

[image: Annotated orbital image of Perseverance rover's landing zone] ([Source](https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/25630/perseverance-and-mars-2020-spacecraft-components-on-the-surface/), [Unannotated higher-res original](https://mars.nasa.gov/system/downloadable_items/45706_PIA24333.jpg))

Comment: Note that Perseverance is the middle dot of the three.  The other two white spots in that box are blast effects from the skycrane.